# Is there a problem with BufferedWriter in JAVA?

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

I'm quite **new** in OOP and Java programming, so please, **forgive me**.
I wrote a small class in which I try to **write** a String in a file using the **BufferedReader class**.
Everything works just fine, but the file is **"empty"**, I mean that I can't see anything inside.

But for sure, data are stored, because when I close Eclipse and re open it again and run the driver class to make my tests, data are restored from the file.
By the way I use a **"try with resources"** mechanism so my file is **"closed"** automatically.

Does someone already meet this problem?
My **Eclipse** version is **"2018-12"**

Below, you have the small class with a "writeToFile" method in which I use the **BufferedReader class**.

```
package parlons.code.tipcalulator.utilities;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileManagement {
    private File tipFile;
    
    public FileManagement(String tipsFileName) {
        this.tipFile = new File("/"+tipsFileName);
        
    }
    public String readFromFile() {
        String tip = null;
        try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.tipFile))) {
            tip = bufferedReader.readLine();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tip;
        
    }
    
    public void writeToFile(String decimal) {
        try(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tipFile,true))){
            bufferedWriter.write(decimal);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below, you'll find the Driver class for testing purposes.

```
package parlons.code.tipcalulator.utilities;

public class UtilitiesTestDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String decimal = "108";
        FileManagement fileManagement = new FileManagement("tipFile.txt");
        fileManagement.writeToFile(decimal);
        System.out.println(fileManagement.readFromFile());
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine on my machine.  Are you sure you have the permissions you need to write to the folder you're specifying?  I see that you're attempting to write to `/tipFile.txt` which would put the file at the root folder (which is most certainly *not* where you want to write the file).

Comment: Method [getAbsolutePath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath--), in class `java.io.File`, will show you the full path to your `tipFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Makoto's comment above, everything works fine if you change to e.g.:

```
        this.tipFile = new File("./"+tipsFileName);
```

This would create the tipFile.txt file (containing 108) in the root directory of your project (as opposed to the root of the filesystem - where you would probably not have write permission.)